# can not implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.Ienumerable<string> to system.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have following test code and i just want to select names of countries, like :

```
var countries = new[]
{
    new { Name = "Frankrijk", Oppervlake = 643274 },
    new { Name = "Nederland", Oppervlake = 41528},
    new { Name = "Belgium", Oppervlake = 25812}
};

Console.WriteLine("selected name");
output = countries.Where(x => x.Oppervlake > 100).Select(x => x.Name);
```

then i get error as:
can not implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>` to `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>`

Can someone tell me why? Linq is supposed to can be used on any collections , is it?

Thanks everyone, the problem is indeed on the type of **output**. I have already assigned another type to it before, the code is :

```
var output = countries.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

and i know now that compiler will give the type of the initial value of a **var** variable.
That is why i get this error. Thanks again everyone :)

@Jon Skeet: Thanks for your comment, i am still not very familiar with how to post here, but i very pay more attention later :)

Comment: what is `output` type?

Comment: Whitespace is your friend. Please use it wisely. Look how much more readable your `countries` initialization is now...

Comment: my guess is you have used the output variable before in a different statement, and we are not seeing all the relevant code.

Comment: yes @Dennis_E is right, you are already assigning some result to `output`

Comment: Need more information. I cannot reproduce error, see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y0S4CU

Comment: Yes, @Dennis_E,you are right. I have assigned another type to **output** before, the code as:                                                    var output = landen.OrderBy(x => x.Name); - but **output** is a var, i can still reassigned another type to it, isn't it?

Comment: @echo No. Var doesn't mean they type can change. Var is just a shortcut to make compiler guess what type the variable should be from the right side of the initialization. After that it's fixed.

Comment: If your problem is solved please accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you used the output variable in another statement, like

```
var output = countries.OrderBy(...)
```

Then, the Type of output is `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>`

The line

```
countries.Where(x => x.Oppervlake > 100).Select(x => x.Name);
```

will produce a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>`

You cannot assign that to output, because it has a different type.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `output` isn't the correct type to store the result of your linq query.

Try making a new variable for this.

```
var moarOutput = countries.Where(x => x.Oppervlake > 100).Select(x => x.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost positive that output is declared as the wrong type. The following code executes without a hitch:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> output;
        var countries = new[]
        {
            new { Name = "Frankrijk", Oppervlake = 643274 },
            new { Name = "Nederland", Oppervlake = 41528},
            new { Name = "Belgium", Oppervlake = 25812}
        };

        Console.WriteLine("selected name");
        output = countries.Where(x => x.Oppervlake > 100).Select(x => x.Name);
        foreach (var v in output)
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```